# Testing React Hooks: How could I test an Axios' call inside useEffect?

Tags: reactjs, axios, enzyme, react-hooks

I really want to test this piece of code but I haven't found any possible solution for the request that is triggered inside the useEffect(). Any idea?

**useRequestAPI()** -> A custom hook that triggers requests to the server.

**getSpeedRunList()** -> Triggers an Axios' action to an API.

```
import useRequestAPI from 'app/hooks/useRequestAPI';
import { getSpeedRunList } from 'app/api/SpeedRunAPI';
import './Home.scss';

const Home = () => {
  const [{ data, loading, error }, setAxio] = useRequestAPI();

  React.useEffect(() => {
    setLoading(loading);

    if (!data && !error) {
      setAxio(getSpeedRunList);
    }
  }, [data, loading]);

  return (
    <main className="Home">
      // Do some stuff with the data
    </main>
  );
};

export default Home;
```

Comment: In react-dom 16.9.0-alpha is `async act()`. It makes testing async calls in `useEffect` possible. Also moving the call itself to separate function makes testing much easier